# JsonObjectRequest keeps throwing null pointer exception when it's not null

Tags: java, android, json, google-places-api, jsonobjectrequest

I'm currently trying to implement JsonObjectRequest. I'm looking for a location and trying to get the place's information. However, there is a problem with jsObjRequest (of type JsonObjectRequest)--it throws a null pointer exception even though it's not null when I check on the watchlist. I'm confused as to why. Here's the code:

```
private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
private static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyBlOhVQWuyQGwlAGZnDo81Aeg50UJbFrfw";

private static final String PLACES_SEARCH_URL =
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
private static final String PLACES_TEXT_SEARCH_URL =
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
private static final String PLACES_DETAILS_URL =
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?";

private double _latitude;
private double _longitude;
private double _radius;

/**
 * Searching places
 * @param latitude - latitude of place
 * @params longitude - longitude of place
 * @param radius - radius of searchable area
 * //@param types - type of place to search
 * @return list of places
 * */
public PlacesList search(double latitude, double longitude, double radius/*, String types*/)
        throws Exception {

    String url = PLACES_SEARCH_URL + "key=" + API_KEY + "&location=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&radius=" + radius;
    System.out.println(url);
    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        Log.d("SEARCH", "Part 1");
                        VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d("SEARCH", "Part 2 - Exception called");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Exception caught in JsonObjectRequest");
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("SEARCH", "Part 3");
                    VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                }
            });
    ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
    return new PlacesList();
}
```

It throws on the line that contains: **ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);**

The following block of code is where we catch the exception:

```
// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
        Double lat = location.getLatitude();
        Double lon = location.getLongitude();
        PlacesList myPlaces = new PlacesList();
        try {
            myPlaces = finder.search(lat, lon, 10);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not find place. Exception in search.");
        }
        if (myPlaces.getMostLikelyPlace() != null) {
            if (myPlaces.getMostLikelyPlace().getId() != null) {
                Log.d("PLACEID", myPlaces.getMostLikelyPlace().getId());
                System.out.println(myPlaces.getMostLikelyPlace().getId());
            }
        }
    }
```

The error that we catch looks like this:

I/System.out: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?key=AIzaSyBlOhVQWuyQGwlAGZnDo81Aeg50UJbFrfw&location=43.816,-111.78199833333335&radius=10.0

I/System.out: Could not find place. Exception in search.

Here is what the documentation says about JsonObjectRequest: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html#request-json

I feel like I'm following the instructions on the documentation exactly. Is there any reason as to why it's throwing on that line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this setup for volley..

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

maybe something went wrong with the volley setup for the project .. happens with me all the time..

Comment: if volley setup was done correct and was working for other stuff .. let me know..

Comment: The setup works, and I'm not getting the same errors, but I'm getting VolleyError in onErrorResponse. When I try to print the error message with VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());, it tells me nothing. All it says is "E/Volley: [1] 2.onErrorResponse: Error:". Any insight as to why this might be happening? Thank you so much for your time.